# Angular UI Router Transition HookMatchCriteria not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, transition

My run block is as follows:

```
angular.module('app', [...]).run(['$transitions', '$state', 'EmployeeService', ($transitions, $state, EmployeeService) => {
    $transitions.onBefore(
        { to: 'app.*' },
        () => EmployeeService.checkAuth().then(() => {
            console.log("run success");
        },
        () => {
            console.log("run caught");
            return $state.target('login');
        }),
        {priority: 10}
    );
}])
```

And for some reason it executes for states 'app' and 'login' though they don't match 'app.*' match criteria, and thus it brings me to infinite loop when performing the logout. What is the right syntax to specify the match criteria ? I've already looked here:
https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/transition.hookmatchcriteria.html

Edit: Posting routes configurations as requested
Routes for the main module (includes 'app' state which shouldn't fire the auth check):

```
export default mainPageRoutesConfig;

function mainPageRoutesConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    "ngInject";
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/',
            component: 'main'
        })
        .state('app.timesheet', {
            url: 'timesheet',
            component: 'timesheet'
        })
        .state('app.saveHours', {
            url: 'saveTaskHours',
            component: 'saveTaskHours',
            params: {
                timesheet:null
            }
        })
}
```

Routes for the employee module (includes 'login' state which shouldn't fire the auth check as well):

```
export default employeesRoutesConfig;

function employeesRoutesConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    "ngInject";

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: 'login',
            component: 'login'
        })  
        .state('app.employeesList', {
            url: 'employees',
            component: 'employeesList'
        })
        .state('app.saveEmployee', {
            url: 'employee/?Id',
            component: 'saveEmployee'
        })
        .state('app.deleteEmployee', {
            url: 'employee/:Id',
            component: 'deleteEmployee'
        })
        .state('app.employeePage', {
            url: 'profile/:Id',
            component: 'employeePage'
        })
}
```

Comment: Please post your routes as well.

Comment: > What is the right syntax to specify the match criteria ?

--- 

Your syntax looks correct.  I wonder if this is a bug.  What version of ui-router? 1.0.0-rc.1?

Answer (score 2):

The solution (though not really an answer) was to specify match criteria as a function:

```
        {
            to: function(state) {
                return state.name !== 'app.login' && state.name !== 'app.error';
            }
        }
```

And the full code (after moving to separate file):

```
export default ($transitions, $state, EmployeeService) => {
    $transitions.onBefore(
        {
            to: function(state) {
                return state.name !== 'app.login' && state.name !== 'app.error';
            }
        },
        () => EmployeeService.checkAuth().then(() => {
            console.log("run block. Authorization check succeeded");
        },
        () => {
            console.log("run block. Authorization check failed");
            return $state.target('app.login');
        }),
        {priority: 10}
    );
}])
```